# Does this C++ sample code contains Data Race?

Tags: c++

Suppose there are not compiler reorderings.

```
int32_t value;
int32_t flag = 0;

// thread 1
void UpdateValue(int32_t x) {
  value = x;
  flag = 1;
}

// thread 2
void DoSomething() {
  while (flag == 0);
  
  do_something(value);
}
```

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model, evaluation `flag = 1` and evaluation `flag == 0` conflict.

And:

- flag is not atomic variable
- there is no signal handler
- `flag = 1` doesn't happens before `flag == 0`

So there is data race?

But in this sample code, every read/write is atomic(`4 bytes aligned`).

I don't find any undefined behavior and I'm confused...

Comment: What is UB is defined by the standard alone, so aligned `int32_t` access being atomic on some processor doesn't affect it. One possible effect is the compiler optimizing away the repeated read of `flag` in the loop condition, since as far as it can tell, nothing ever changes it (in that thread).

Comment: Yes it is data race. There are memory hardware optimizations which can lead to reorder of memory updates (note that there are couple levels of cache). Even adding volatile will not help with that.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Can I say that, the program will perform very well in x86 machine, but the code itself is still UB? if compiler optimization disabled.

Comment: @MarekR I have learned something about memory reorder, e.g. StoreLoad reorder in TSO. but I don't quite understand the relationship between data race and memory reordering.

Comment: The standard doesn't describe optimizations (with irrevelant exceptions), hence they have no effect on UB. *"the program will perform very well in x86 machine"* I may have believed you if your program was written in assembly. But since you wrote it in C++, the UB can confuse your compiler and make it produce assembly that doesn't do what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

the data race here is a UB and you can expect any behavior including the one that you expect.

The [order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) different threads read/write that location may
help to understand why it is a UB:

> std::memory_order specifies how memory accesses, including regular,
> non-atomic memory accesses, are to be ordered around an atomic
> operation. Absent any constraints on a multi-core system, when
> multiple threads simultaneously read and write to several variables,
> one thread can observe the values change in an order different from
> the order another thread wrote them. Indeed, the apparent order of
> changes can even differ among multiple reader threads. Some similar
> effects can occur even on uniprocessor systems due to compiler
> transformations allowed by the memory model.